# Why error messages after installing MiKTeX on Windows?

Tags: errors, miktex, kpfonts

I just wrote a simple example, only for trying out how it would work on windows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
hello world 
\end{document}
```

And I got this error:

`! LaTeX Error: File 'kpfonts.sty' not found.`

EDIT: I checked that the package is actually installed, so it's on my computer, the compiler just can't find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Try running `Refresh FNDB`with `MiKTeX Settings`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the servers. 
https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-6351

Comment: Hopefully the server will come back online soon- we're already an hour over the ETA.

Comment: Is there an update to this? The outage post has been removed but MikTEX is still not working